# How to catch exceptions in Flutter streambuilder's stream

Tags: firebase, flutter

I want to use try{} catch(){} in my StreamBuilder's Stream, because ${globals.currentUid} is initially set as ''(empty string) and makes exception when the program first runs,
but I can't find any way to make try catch in stream.

Below is my streamBuilder

```
StreamBuilder(
                            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                .collection(
                                    'user/${globals.currentUid}/friends')
                                .snapshots(),
                            builder: (BuildContext context,
                                AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                              if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                  ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                return Center(
                                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                );
                              }
                              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                return Text(
                                  'Error: ${snapshot.error}',
                                );
                              }

                              final docs = snapshot.data!.docs;
                              return Text(
                                  docs.length.toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  ));
                            }),
```

This code makes this error :
*_AssertionError ('package:cloud_firestore/src/firestore.dart': Failed assertion: line 63 pos 7: '!collectionPath.contains('//')': a collection path must not contain "//")*

What I want to do is this below,

```
try{
                        StreamBuilder(
                            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                .collection(
                                    'user/${globals.currentUid}/friends')
                                .snapshots(),
                            builder: (BuildContext context,
                                AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                              if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                  ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                return Center(
                                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                );
                              }
                              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                return Text(
                                  'Error: ${snapshot.error}',
                                );
                              }

                              final docs = snapshot.data!.docs;
                              return Text(docs.length.toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  ));
                            })
                            } on _AssertionError catch(e){
                                  return Text('0',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  ));
                                }
```

and this is grammatically wrong. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception in this case is not actually produced by the stream, but rather by the `collection` method that is called with an invalid argument. You'll probably want to completely avoid creating the `StreamBuilder` until `globals.currentUid` has been initialized with a valid value.

You can do so with a simple `if` statement or with the ternary conditional operator. For example, assuming your StreamBuilder is child to a Container:

```dart
Container(
    child: globals.currentUid != '' ?
        StreamBuilder( // This will be built only if currentUid is not empty
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection(
                        'user/${globals.currentUid}/friends')
                    .snapshots(),
            builder: (
                BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot snapshot,
            ) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                }

                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                }

                final docs = snapshot.data!.docs;
                return Text(
                    docs.length.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                );
            },
        )
        : Container(), // An empty container will be shown if currentUid is empty
),
```